# Rank multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a dataset of a series with missing values that I want to replace by the index. The second column contains the same numbers than the first column, but in a different order.

here's an example:

```
>>> df
ind    u    v   d
0      5    7   151
1      7    20  151
2      8    40  151
3      20   5   151
```

this should turn out to:

```
>>>df
ind    u    v   d
0      1    2   151
1      2    4   151
2      3    5   151
3      4    1   151
```

i reindexed the values in row 'u' by creating a new column:

```
>>>df['new_index'] = range(1, len(numbers) + 1)
```

but how do I now replace values of the second column referring to the indexes?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: "The second column contains the same numbers than the first column, but in a different order." Doesn't seem so in your example.

Comment: @ Ami: True, it contains same numbers and might also contain some more/less numbers. Numbers might also occur multiple times in a collumn.

Comment: "it contains same numbers and might also contain some more/less numbers" That sort of renders "contains the same numbers than the first column" meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html), but first need create `Series` with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last create `DataFrame` with `unstack` again:

```
df[['u','v']] = df[['u','v']].unstack().rank(method='dense').astype(int).unstack(0)
print (df)
     u  v    d
ind           
0    1  2  151
1    2  4  151
2    3  5  151
3    4  1  151
```

If use only [`DataFrame.rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), output in `v` is different:

```
df[['u','v']] = df[['u','v']].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
print (df)
     u  v    d
ind           
0    1  2  151
1    2  3  151
2    3  4  151
3    4  1  151
```

Comment: nice Thanks! Thats exacly what I've been looking for!