# Ranking using multiple columns within groups allowing for tied ranks in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, grouping, ranking

#### Intro and problem

How can I rank observations within groups where the ranking is based on more than just one column and where the ranking allows for tied ranks?

I know how to calculate aggregated group-level statistics using the `groupby()` method and I also know how to rank using multiple columns without groups (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974374/pandas-rank-by-multiple-columns), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854731/rank-multiple-columns-in-pandas) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974374/pandas-rank-by-multiple-columns)). The main problem seems to be getting both ideas (grouping & ranking) to play nicely together.

[This other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489613/pandas-group-by-and-rank-within-group-based-on-multiple-columns) has some ideas on how to solve the problem, but its results don't show you which rows are tied - it just returns an array of ever-increasing ranks even when the values are identical. The problem is described in more detail in the example I created below.

#### Minimal reproducible example

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'row_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                   'Group':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                   'Var1':[100,100,100,200,200,300,300,400,400,400],
                   'Var2':[5,5,6,7,8,1,1,2,2,3]})
print(df)

#    row_id  Group  Var1  Var2
# 0       1      1   100     5
# 1       2      1   100     5
# 2       3      1   100     6
# 3       4      1   200     7
# 4       5      1   200     8
# 5       6      2   300     1
# 6       7      2   300     1
# 7       8      2   400     2
# 8       9      2   400     2
# 9      10      2   400     3
```

In the case above, I would like to group using the `Group` variable and rank using the `Var1` and `Var2` variables. Therefore, I expect the output to look like this:

```py
#    row_id  Group  Var1  Var2  Rank
# 0       1      1   100     5     1
# 1       2      1   100     5     1
# 2       3      1   100     6     3
# 3       4      1   200     7     4
# 4       5      1   200     8     5
# 5       6      2   300     1     1
# 6       7      2   300     1     1
# 7       8      2   400     2     3
# 8       9      2   400     2     3
# 9      10      2   400     3     5
```

#### What I've tried

Using the data in the example above, if I would like to group using the `Group` variable and only rank based on the `Var1` column, that would be pretty easy:

```py
df['Rank_Only_Var1'] = df.groupby('Group')['Var1'].rank(method='min', ascending=True)

print(df)

#    row_id  Group  Var1  Var2  Rank_Only_Var1
# 0       1      1   100     5             1.0
# 1       2      1   100     5             1.0
# 2       3      1   100     6             1.0
# 3       4      1   200     7             4.0
# 4       5      1   200     8             4.0
# 5       6      2   300     1             1.0
# 6       7      2   300     1             1.0
# 7       8      2   400     2             3.0
# 8       9      2   400     2             3.0
# 9      10      2   400     3             3.0
```

However, if I want to group using the `Group` variable and rank using the `Var1` and `Var2` variables, things get hairy. Using the approach suggested [by this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489613/pandas-group-by-and-rank-within-group-based-on-multiple-columns), we arrive at the following results:

```py
df = df.sort_values(['Var1', 'Var1'], ascending=[True, True])
df['overall_rank'] = 1
df['overall_rank'] = df.groupby(['Group'])['overall_rank'].cumsum()

print(df)

#    row_id  Group  Var1  Var2  overall_rank
# 0       1      1   100     5             1
# 1       2      1   100     5             2
# 2       3      1   100     6             3
# 3       4      1   200     7             4
# 4       5      1   200     8             5
# 5       6      2   300     1             1
# 6       7      2   300     1             2
# 7       8      2   400     2             3
# 8       9      2   400     2             4
# 9      10      2   400     3             5
```

Note how the first and second rows have identical values for `Var1` and `Var2`, but the first row is ranked 1 and the second row is ranked 2. Those two rows **shouldn't** have different ranks. Their ranks should be identical and tied, because the values the rank is based on are identical and tied. This problem also happens with rows 6 & 7 as well as with rows 8 & 9.

I even tried adapting the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045215/8667016), but it doesn't work when we have a `groupby` statement.

#### Back to the heart of the question

How can I rank observations within groups where the ranking is based on more than just one column and where the ranking allows for tied ranks?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I just edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you can't use the linked solution with a `.groupby`

You can also replace the `.apply` for better performance:

```
(df.assign(key = list(map(tuple, df[['Var1', 'Var2']].values)))
   .groupby('Group')['key'].rank('dense'))
```

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    4.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
9    3.0
Name: key, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! I was getting the order of operations wrong: I tried using the `groupby` **before** the `assign`/`apply` commands. This works perfectly! Thanks again!

Comment: Do you happen to know how to control the order in which the ranking is done for each variable? For example, say we want to rank `Var1` in ascending order but `Var2` in descending order. Is that possible?

Comment: The only trick I can think of is to figure out which columns you want to be treated in the inverse order and just multiply them by -1 using an `assign` statement`. So in this case, if we want to do ascending by `Var1` and descending by `Var2`, we could do the following: ```(df.assign(Var2_Inv = -df['Var2'],
           key = list(map(tuple, df[['Var1', 'Var2_Inv']].values)))
   .groupby('Group')['key']
   .rank('dense', ascending=True))```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a better way than doing what you've suggested.